# Having difficulty getting ZeroBrane to highlight code, autocomplete, etc

Tags: zerobrane

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VeWP.jpg

Here is an example. For some reason code is simply not being highlighted using the Lua 5.2 interpreter. Autocomplete doesn't appear to be working correctly either. Also whenever I declare a function it doesn't automatically add a space in the middle and the end at the bottom which I've seen. These would all be immensely helpful starting off. I have never coded before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the highlighting, as the Lua code in your snapshot is highlighted. I'm not sure why auto-complete is not working in your case, but if you type "pr" and don't see "print" and "pairs" offered when Lua 5.2 interpreter is selected, you may want to [open a ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues) and we'll investigate.